telegram bot API 'setMyName' doesn't work
Here is my code
import requests
import json
bot_token = " "  # your bot token
token_url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/"

parameters = {
    "name": "sdfjk123",
    "language_code": "en"
}
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

print(token_url+'setMyName')


def set_name():
    r = requests.post(token_url+'setMyName', json=json.dumps(parameters), headers=headers)
    print(r.json())


set_name()


Here is the error message returned by the request
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: BOT_TITLE_INVALID'}
What have I tried
First of all, I checked my token and it has no errors, secondly
I tried using request.get(url,params=parameters), which did return success, but the bot name didn't change, so I used the method above. Also, I have used setMyDescription and setMyCommands, which also return success but the bot does not change. It seems that the bot doesn't change when I use the relevant setup parameters, but when I use the query and other parameters, the corresponding information is returned!
Is there any way to fix this?
The problem has been solved
use requests.post(token_url+'setMyName', json=parameters), do not use the json.dumps()!!!

You are passing your data as json=json.dumps(parameters) but you need to use the data param from requests.

The following code allows me to update the Bot's username
import requests
import json

bot_token = "xxx"  # your bot token
token_url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/"

parameters = {
    "name": "FooBar",
    "language_code": ""
}

def set_name():
    r = requests.post(token_url+'setMyName', data=json.dumps(parameters))
    print(r.json())

set_name()

Response:
{'ok': True, 'result': True}


I used your code with my bot token and the request still returns {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: BOT_TITLE_INVALID'}

Don't use json, use data=json.dumps(parameters)

thanks,I'm using requests.post(token_url+'setMyName', json=parameters) and it returns success and the bot's name is changed

Glad it worked as shown in my answer! Please accept the answer, it will give both of us some rep ;)
